# ClosedXML throwing an exception when deployed to aws lambda

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, aws-lambda, closedxml

I have an AWS lambda that reads data from an excel file. I have used `ClosedXml v 0.93.0` with `.net core 2`.

The function works as expected when running on localhost but gives an error:

> {"error":"The type initializer for 'ClosedXML.Excel.XLHelper' threw an exception."}

when deployed on AWS lambda.

**updated with stack trace:**

> at ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorksheet.Ranges(String ranges)\n
>       at ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook.LoadSheetViews(SheetViews sheetViews, XLWorksheet ws)\n
>       at ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook.LoadSpreadsheetDocument(SpreadsheetDocument dSpreadsheet)\n
>       at ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook.LoadSheets(Stream stream)\n
>       at Business.Services.ImportService.ValidateExcel(Stream excelData, Guid clientId) 
>       in Business\Services\ImportService.cs:line 38\n
>       at Business.Controllers.CommonDataBusinessController.Import(IFormCollection files) 
>       in Business\Controllers\CommonDataBusinessController.cs:line 61\n
>       at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\n
>       at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.Execute(Object target, Object[] parameters)\n
>       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.d__12.MoveNext()\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n
>       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\n
>       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\n
>       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.d__10.MoveNext()\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n
>       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\n
>       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContext context)\n
>       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)\n
>       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.d__14.MoveNext()\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n
>       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\n
>       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.d__22.MoveNext()\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n
>       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)\n
>       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)\n
>       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.d__17.MoveNext()\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n
>       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\n
>       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.d__15.MoveNext()\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n
>       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\n
>       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.d__4.MoveNext()\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n
>       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\n
>       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.d__6.MoveNext()\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n
>       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\n
>       at Business.ErrorHandlingMiddleware.d__3.MoveNext() in 
>       D:Business\ErrorHandlingMiddleware.cs:line 28

Comment: any more details about the exception?

Comment: You should log the base exception if you can't log the stack trace in the first place.

Comment: @trailmax updated the question with stack trace

Comment: @YeshwantParab does it give you message/type of exception? looks like the file it tries to open is not excel/does not exist or otherwise corrupted.

Comment: ClosedXML developer here. Please log this on the Github repo.

Comment: @FrancoisBotha I have created a issue on Github, you can find my issue at https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/issues/970